# Using Async/Await vs .then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm a bit confused with the async/await concept, especially when it comes to using it compared to .then() in a function.

I'm currently playing around with a basic React application and fetching some data in a `useEffect`

I was wondering, as a `fetch` returns a `Promise` why do I not need to mark anything as `async` or `await` when doing the following example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("whatever").then(res => console.log(res));
  }, [])
```

but when I choose to do `await` I would need to wrap the code in an `async` function

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // error, needs to be in an async function
    const res = await fetch("whatever");
  },[])
```

I guess my question is really what is the difference between chaining with `.then()` vs using `async` `await` and why doesnt `.then()` require me to await anything, even if the fetch returns a promise?

Thanks

Comment: Because your first snippet wouldn't expect your promise to be resolved before the callback finishes, but your second does ...

Comment: @derpirscher could you expand on this explanation a little more? What do you mean by “the first snippet wouldn’t expect your promise to be resolved before the callback finishes”? Does the callback not execute when the promise IS resolved?

Comment: Sorry for unclear wording. With "callback" I mean the function you pass to `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

Async/await is "just" syntactic sugar. It allows you to write nice asynchronous code, and it looks like it is synchronous. It is easier to follow the control flow, especially when you have multiple functions to wait for. If you use `.then() .catch()` you are in the same callback hell as you were before there were promises.
However, you can only use async/await if the function is async.

```
useEffect(() => {  // async not allowed :/
    const fetchData = async () => {
       const res = await fetch("whatever");
       console.log(res);    // do something with your result
    ]
    fetchData().catch(console.error);  // ok that got ugly.
},[])
```

`useEffect()` seems to be a bad example to demonstrate async/await, but in general, when you use `.then()`, basically a callback is called, when the result is available, hence you do not have to await anything.

Comment: Please note, that you can not use `async` directly in the `useEffect` because the return value of the effect must be void or a clean up function. The default workaround is to define and run an async function inside the effect itself

See: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters

Comment: @DimitriL. thx ... `useEffect` seems to be a real bad example to show the beauty of async/await :D

Comment: @DimitriL. "*must be void or a clean up function*" - if you're using TypeScript, maybe, but otherwise it's just "should", isn't it? React doesn't complain if you return a promise not a function afaict.

Comment: Ok so when using `.then()` the callback only runs when the promise is resolved, but with a sync/await we have to `await` for the promise, as you say really just a syntactic thing?

Comment: Yes, It's a syntactic thing. when you do not `await`, it immediately returns but you get a `Promise<sometype>` back instead of `sometype`. You can then for example start other asynchronous tasks and await for all promises later e.g. with `await Promises.all([p1, p2])`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @HEllRZA, both then() and async/await can be used to handle promises in JavaScript. Then() is a method that takes a callback function as a parameter and allows you to chain multiple then() methods to handle the response in a sequence. Async/await is a new way of writing asynchronous code in JavaScript.